# meaning of edge in this sentence

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

belligerent speeches by leaders of the Soviet Union and the United States throughout the Cold War were keeping the world on edge.

Comment: Again, what research have you done? Have you Googled? In what way didn't that answer your question?

Comment: `edge` only has meaning as part of the idiom `[be] on edge`: it means to have all of one's attention distracted by some remarkable event that is about to happen. (similar is `[be] on the edge of one's seat`)

Comment: @jlovegren 's comment should be the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variant of the idiom "to be on edge" meaning in a state of nervous tension.